# RegEx to select after line

Tags: regex, vim

I'm using vim to edit a document - an excerpt of which is:

```
--

aaa bbb
ccc ddd
eee fff

--

ggg hhh
iii jjj
kkk lll

--
```

I'd like to select all lines that come after (both) lines with "--" and new lines. In this example, I'd like to select "aaa bbb" and "ggg hhh". Is line-level "look behinds" possible in regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim has a nifty feature that you can take advantage of here.  The following command will match the two lines requested (using search as an example):

```
/--\n\n\zs.*
```

The explanation:

- `/` - begin the search
- `--\n\n` - the predicate as I understand the question
- `\zs` - tells vim to begin the actual match here and throw away everything before this
- `.*` - any character.

The `\zs` token allows you to tell vim where the pattern matching actually begins even though the regex as a whole must match.  There is a complementary token `\ze` which tells vim where to end the match.

While I've used the search function to show off this feature, these tokens can be used anywhere you can use a regex in vim.

For more information about this feature take a look at `:help /\zs` and `:help /\ze`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only this kind of data like you provided you could use the lookbehinds with newline characters. Basically matching the line after "--" and a empty line. And answering "is line level lookbehind possible": Yes, a line break is nothing but a character denoted with `\n`.

```
(?<=--\n\n).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/q5VESm/1

Comment: Thats not a vim RE